# CoffeeScript compile error that i can't understand

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I use this command to compile my *.coffee file to ../js folder

```
coffee -o ../js -wcbm ./
```

I excute above command In the first time, everything is ok, *.coffee file is compiled

Then i use "Ctrl+S" to save my coffee file and this coffee file is not change, But i get a error:

```
Bus error: 10
```

Note；everything is ok Yesterday, But when i Upgrade my OSX 10.8 to OSX 10.9, This problem arises

Comment: Looks like your editor crashed. It might be affected by a bug, but there is not enough information for us to help you much. Please at least specify the editor you're using and provide more details about the reproduction steps.

Comment: First update to the latest `node -g update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its problem with your OS X upgrade. NodeJS seems to have problem with watching files, if you upgrade to newest version NodeJS (v0.10.21) after that should be okay. This is helped me.

Comment: But my coffeescript is the latest version, i can't upgrade.

Comment: I upgrade my node to latest version by npm, everything is ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

That solved the Problem, thanks. By the way, a nice way to upgrade Node.js via NPM:

http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs